# Footable, made for bootstrap, does not display icons in columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, icons, html-table, footable

When you will inspect element the `<td>` tag is blank and if you include icon code there it will be displayed, but on page load the column is blank. Kindly refer the link of code below.

```
<td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
</td>
```

goes blank, refer following code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/s3kz3owDVg1qHjkFJe01?p=preview

Comment: include the `/fonts` folder to use all glyphicons.

Comment: I have done that in my project, but they are not available then to. You see plus/minus icons, they are glyphicon itself.

Comment: it is showing the glyphicons outside the table but not inside it. I Tried don't know why? May be something by the footable.

Comment: Screenshot: http://imgur.com/6pYkyBk

Comment: I just commented the footable import and the glyphicons worked fine in table.

Comment: See http://imgur.com/9gvUIHu

Answer (score 1):

You need to add data-type="html" to any header or cell that will contain HTML. By default HTML is sanitized for sorting purposes. You can read more about it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable/issues/355).